# Malicious smart contract that transfers tokens forth and back

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-invocation

Sorry if my question was already discussed.

Is it possible to implement such a smart contract or contracts that in result can transfer eth or ERC20 tokens forth from ANY to B account and back from B to ANY in one single transaction?
And token transfers will be reflected in the transaction's receipt event log or debug traces.

Account B is my custodial account, so it has no opportunity to approve anything to anybody.

I am going to parse just deposit transactions to B accounts initiated by third party smart contracts and I do not want to be fooled by such a malicious logic when somebody deposits the amount to B and takes it back.

Answer (score 0):

No, that logic (to allow for transfers without approval) would have to be implemented in the ERC20 contract itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, no matter if it's the same transaction, nobody can get assets from B if it has not given approval